Inovua React Data Grid using Safari: Bugs with scrolling
The Inovua React Data Grid is working as expected on Edge, but on Safari we are experiencing some issues:

Vertical scrolling is jerky and the vertical scrollbar has some sort of "shadow"/second scrollbar issue (see screenshot below). Expected it to scroll smoothly.
Horizontal scrollbar is only visible if you scroll right to the bottom of the grid, whereas on Edge the horizontal scrollbar is visible at any time. Tried to scroll horizontally when not at the bottom of the grid, but scrollbar was not visible. Expected it to be visible at all times.

Screenshot of React Data Grid vertical scrollbar issue in Safari
Using @inovua/reactdatagrid-enterprise v5.10.2

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
